# Passing negative numbers to lineTo/strokeRect/fillRect

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

The subject says it all: can you pass negative numbers to the drawing primitives in HMTL5 canvas?

For example, if I translate to (100,100), can I then draw a rectangle, or line using the coordinates (-25,-25)? Simple testing with lineTo suggests not, but no errors result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass negative values. The only thing that will happen is that graphics outside the canvas' bitmap will be clipped.

Translating the canvas moves its origin point (0,0). If you translated for example to the right and down and you want to draw to the left and top (assuming no rotation has been applied) you will *have* to use negative values.

```
ctx.translate(100, 100);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(-100, -100);
ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
ctx.stroke();
```

draws a line from upper left corner to 100,100.

**[Online demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/hr65N/)**